# I cannot create a virtualbox with Terraform provider shekeriev/virtualbox

Tags: terraform, virtualbox

I'm using this provider - [shekeriev/virtualbox/0.0.4][1]

```
terraform -v
Terraform v1.3.6
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/shekeriev/virtualbox v0.0.4
```

my configuration file main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    virtualbox = {
      source = "shekeriev/virtualbox"
      version = "0.0.4"
    }
  }
}

provider "virtualbox" {
  # Configuration options
}

resource "virtualbox_vm" "node" {
  count     = 1
  name      = format("node-%02d", count.index + 1)
  image     = "https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64/versions/20190507.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box"
  cpus      = 1
  memory    = "512 mib"

  network_adapter {
    type           = "hostonly"
    device         = "IntelPro1000MTDesktop"
    host_interface = "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
  }
}
```

them i'm typing

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply  
yes
```

and getting this error!

```
Error: failed to unpack image https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64/versions/20190507.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box: error unpacking gold image virtualbox.box: exit status 2  
│
│   with virtualbox_vm.node[0],
│   on main.tf line 18, in resource "virtualbox_vm" "node":
│   18: resource "virtualbox_vm" "node" {
```

I've tried different images and provider terra-farm but after all they returning this error.
[1]: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/shekeriev/virtualbox/0.0.4

Answer (score 2):

This is a script that actually works, i dont know whos the fault but there is seriously bug, for some reason vagrant.box keeps on the cache after terraform destroy, DO NOT USE THE HTTPS REPOSITORY AS IMAGE, instead, download the image, rename it and put it on a local directory.

I hope it helps you, thank you

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    virtualbox = {
      source = "shekeriev/virtualbox"
      version = "0.0.4"
    }
  }
}


provider "virtualbox" {
   delay      = 60
   mintimeout = 10
}


resource "virtualbox_vm" "node" {
  count = 1
  name  = "${ format("node-%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  #image  = "https://app.vagrantup.com/alpine/boxes/alpine64/versions/3.7.0/providers/virtualbox/unknown/vagrant.box"
  image  = "/local/path/image.box"
  cpus      = 2
  memory    = "2048 mib"
  #user_data = file("${path.module}/user_data")

  network_adapter {
    type           = "bridged"
    #device         = "IntelPro1000MTDesktop"
    host_interface = "eth0"
    # On Windows use this instead
    # host_interface = "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "ssh_docker" {
  # Other resource settings  
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "vagrant"
    password = "vagrant"
    #private_key = file("/path/to/your/private/key.pem")
    host        = virtualbox_vm.node[0].network_adapter[0].ipv4_address
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo 'Hello, World'",
      #"sudo apt-get update",
      #"sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg"
    ]
  }

}


output "IPAddress" {
  value = element(virtualbox_vm.node.*.network_adapter.0.ipv4_address, 1)
}

# output "IPAddress" {
#   value = element(virtualbox_vm.node.*.network_adapter.0.ipv4_address, 1)
# }
```

Comment: change `name  = "${ format("node-%02d", count.index + 1)}"` to `name  = format("node-%02d", count.index + 1)`

and specify `wget https://app.vagrantup.com/alpine/boxes/alpine64/versions/3.7.0/providers/virtualbox/unknown/vagrant.box -o image.box`.  

I'm currently unable to get this erroring on windows: "Error: failed to wait until VM is ready: waiting for VM (alpine-node-01) to become ready: unable to read VM".  I'm suspecting it's because it's not logging in on startup and I can't figure out why.